# Error with "Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 349; received: 0)"

Tags: java, http, response, httpresponse

When performing a POST request to the server, and I call readEntity, I am presented with the error "Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 349; received: 0)".

At first, I thought the server was returning me 0 bytes, but when making the same request via postman, the return comes correctly. I also captured the network packets with WireShark, what I could see in the packages is that the header comes in one package and the body in another. I don't know if that would be the problem. Another thing I noticed is that the connection is terminated with an RST, as shown below:

https://i.ibb.co/MSGhHJM/Wire-Shark.png

Following is code snippets, where the line that occurs the error is: `params = post.readEntity(HashMap.class);`

Config class imports:

```java
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.JSONArray;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Config class:

```java
public void configure(SchedulerModule module, SessionInfo session) {
    Response post = connection.post(session, ServiceURL.CONFIG_URL, new JSONArray());
    params = post.readEntity(HashMap.class); // Linha que o erro ocorre
    if ("R".equals(params.get("IE_TIPO")) && validaInteger(params.get("QT_INTERVALO")) > 0) {
        module.setDelay(validaInteger(params.get("QT_INTERVALO")));
        module.setRate(validaInteger(params.get("QT_INTERVALO")));
        isRun = true;
    } else {
        isRun = false;
    }
}
```

Connection class imports:

```java
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;
import org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.JSONArray;
import org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.JSONObject;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Connection class method:

```java
public Response post(SessionInfo sessionInfo, ServiceURL url, JSONArray array) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    try {
        Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(backendUrl).path(url.getUrl())
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .header("idSessao", sessionInfo.getIdSessao())
                .header("crsfToken", sessionInfo.getCrsfToken())
                .header("Cookie", sessionInfo.getCookieHeader());

        return builder.post(Entity.entity(array == null ? "[]" : array.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failure" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I need to get the return body of this request. Can you help me?

Comment: Please post all your imports and show all the types of your variables. Eg, what exactly is `connection`

Comment: ```connection.post``` is the call to the method below the referenced code snippet.

Comment: added in the texts the imports.

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Also what JAX-RS implementation are you using, Tomcat? I would step through the source if you can to see why it's throwing that error.

Comment: Weblogic is being used. I'll get the whole pile to send you.